# Getting users from another AD Domain using PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory-group

How would I get users from an AD Group which contains users from different domains.

For example, I have 2 domains in my active directory, **Domain1.corp.com** and **Domain2.corp.com**

I have an AD group called **TestGroup** which contains users from both the domains.

> Domain1 users: TestUser1, TestUser2
>
> Domain2 users: TestUser3, TestUser4, TestUser5
>
> TestGroup users: TestUser1, TestUser2, TestUser3, TestUser5

Following could would return only Domain1 users.

```
string domainname = "Domain1.corp.com:3268";
string usernames = String.Empty;
using (var p_context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainname))
{
     using (var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "TestGroup"))
     {
         var users = group.GetMembers(false);
         foreach (var user in users)
         {
             username = username + ", " + user.SamAccountName;
         }
     }
}
```

When returning the username variable, I would see users from only Domain1.Am I missing anything over here?
My IIS server is located in the Domain1.corp.com

I verified that the server had access to the other domain by running a powershell script which returned users located in both the domains.

```
get-adgroupmember "TestGroup" -recursive
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7073023/326315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the underlying `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` for the group:

```
var groupEntry = (DirectoryEntry)group.GetUnderlyingObject();
```

(Note: according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.getunderlyingobject(v=vs.110).aspx) GetUnderlyingObject() will return a `DirectoryEntry`, even though the return type is `object`.)

From there you can get the member distinguished names:

```
var memberDistinguishedNames = groupEntry.Properties["member"].Cast<string>();
```

The users from the other domain are Foreign Security Principals so the distinguished name will be in the form `CN={SecurityIdentifier},CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals`. You can extract the Security Identifier and search for the user on the other domain/s in order to get the rest of their details. Unfortunately this does mean you need to connect to both domains, which can be slow.